# Save check item data to session when page refresh

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

How to save all my check box item after I click on next page?. This is my code to save the data inside session. But after next page, the session data will dissappear.

```
    Dim StrList As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)()

    For Each r As GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows
        Dim i As Integer = r.RowIndex
        Dim chk As CheckBox = CType(r.FindControl("ChkItem"), CheckBox)

        If chk.Checked = True Then
            Dim HyperLink2 As HyperLink = TryCast(GridView1.Rows(i).FindControl("HyperLink2"), HyperLink)
            StrList.Add(HyperLink2.Text)
        End If
    Next

    Dim countItemList As Integer = StrList.Count
    Dim combindedString As String = String.Join(";", StrList.ToArray())
    Session("itemsList") = combindedString
    Session("itemCount") = countItemList
```

This is my code to save the data. Its work when I not refresh the page. But otherwise when I do a seacrhing or go to next page.

Comment: The whole point of session data is that it exists for the entire session. If the data is being cleared then it's because you're clearing it.

Comment: is there any way to save the data without using session?.

Comment: Try this: https://www.codeguru.com/columns/dotnet/passing-data-between-pages-in-asp.net.htm